How to fix the error "No module named 'apt_pkg'" on Ubuntu 20.04.6?
I am using ubuntu 20.04.6 on a VM running in windows 10 and I have trouble installing a package so that the command
python3 -c "import apt_pkg; print('apt_pkg module is available.')"

works correctly. I get an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

I updated the python version to 3.11.9 and I tried to install the package using the commands
sudo apt install python3-apt
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH

Anything that I am missing?

Did you change your system's version of python?

You do mention python 3.11, but that is not the version of python3 that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses, and apt is a tool that relies on the default python3 version to work. Either your release of python3 version (if 3.11 is the default version) is incorrect as they do not match.

The python version in 20.04 is 3.8. Did you change the default python version? (If so, restore back, it may break Ubuntu otherwise). Are you using a python 3.11 virtual environment?

@guiverc There is no release in Ubuntu where the default python version is 3.11.9 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3&searchon=names

Yes I updated the version of python.

That's your problem then.

and that is why I am asking a question ...

So that means I cannot install a different version of python on Ubuntu?

@Alex You can but NOT by replacing your current Python on your system.  You need to use something like https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv (not affiliated to it) to create Python builds in user space and use those versions.  You should NEVER change your system python versions.

But how can I run python code I have to run as root on a ubuntu VM system with some minimum version? How can I do that?
